# python code not working after copied from windows to linux

Tags: python, linux, windows

I just wrote a small program in python, which is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "hello"
```

It works in windows. And when I type this code in linux, it works, too.

But when I copy the python file from windows to linux in my VBox, this code doesn't work, and an error appears which is:
: no such file or directory
Why does that happen? And what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps the shebang is at fault?

Comment: but when I type the same code under linux environment, it works. It just doesn't work when I copy my file from windows to linux

Comment: You haven't really given enough information about your environment for this to be answerable. One guess is that whatever execution environment you have in Windows is trying to interpret that shebang you have in your file:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you get an error because of different line endings on windows and linux? Windows uses "\r\n" and Linux just "\n".

You could write script that would get rid of "\r" on linux, for example:

EDIT: I have realized that carriage returns are seen only in binary mode. So script should do something like this

```
with open('myscript.py', 'rb') as file:
    data = file.read()
    data = data.replace(b'\r\n', b'\n')
with open('myscript.py', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: You are right! and when I change my line endings to unix, the file works well   in linux